# Difference between this.function and this.function()

Tags: javascript

What is the difference in doing this.functionName vs this.functionName()? I don't have a clear understanding between the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.functionName` reads the value of property `functionName` of the object `this`.

`this.functionName()` reads the value of property `functionName` of the object `this` **and** tries to call it as a function. It will throw an error if the value of `this.functionName` is not a function.

Decompose the statement as

```
this.functionName()
\____callee_____/
\_CallExpression__/
```

"callee" can be any expression but must resolve to a function object.

[Check out the AST](http://felix-kling.de/esprima_ast_explorer/#/MRA1g8xCRj/1) if you are curious.

Answer (score 2):

When evaluated, the first one is just a reference to the function, in the second case the function gets executed, and the expression will be evaluated to be the return value of the function.

Answer (score 1):

this.functionName returns the function itself, this.functionName() will execute the function and return the result

```
function A() { 
    this.doSomething = function() { 
        return "A"; 
    } 

    this.doOtherThing = function() { 
        console.log(this.doSomething); 
        console.log(this.doSomething());         
    }     
}

var a = new A();
a.doOtherThing()
```

Prints the following to the console:

```
function () { 
  return "A"; 
}

A
```

The first is the function itself, the second is the result of the function. There are a number of reasons you may want to return the function without executing it, for example could pass it to another function to be called after an AJAX request completes.

Answer (score 1):

`this.functionName` is a reference to the function object.

This can be useful if you want to check for the existence of the function before calling it, e.g.

```
if (typeof(this.functionname) == 'function') {
    this.functionname();
}
```

`this.functionName()` actually invokes the function.